# Hopf Algebras of subgroups of $GL_2$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

The Hopf algebra representing the group functor $GL_2$ is the quotient algebra
$$ k[X_{00}, X_{01}, X_{10}, X_{11}, t]/((X_{00}X_{11} - X_{01}X_{10})t -1) $$

Consider the $k$-subspace $D(k) \subset GL_2(k)$ generated by 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
as a one dimensional $k$-vector space.

Is there a Hopf Algebra representation for $D$?

Comment: Let $R$ be the ring $k[A,B,C,D]/(AD-BC-1)$. Let $X=\text{Spec }R$. Then $X(k)$ is the set of morphisms from the "point" $\text{Spec }k$ to $X=\text{Spec }R$. We de-affinize the situation, obtaining the ring morphism $k\leftarrow R$. Such a morphism is given by a suitable choice of the images of $A,B,C,D$ in $k$, If these are $a,b,c,d$, then $ad-bc=1$, so we rather realize $SL_2$ above. For the version that realizes $GL_2$, e.g. $R'=k[A,B,C,D;\nabla]/((AD-BC)\nabla-1)$, the question would maybe be to realize $GL_1$ inside $GL_2$.

Comment: What do you mean by subspace? This is a group, not a vectorspace. The given element forms a closed subgroup, so it does not in any meaningful sense generate anything else.